# How to login into Django LFS as administrator?

Tags: django, authentication, admin, django-lfs

I've installed Django LFS, but have no idea how to login as admin? Where that administrator is being created?
I've tryed to use DB user, but no success...

Comment: I found a Google Groups post that might assist you. [Login as admin](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-lfs/wtyl-4p_s70)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks alot for responces, I've found a solution that worked for me:
I have to do followong:

- cd into buildout directory;
- type: bin/django createsuperuser;
- and fill in the blanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to these (old) docs it is admin/admin.

```
At first you should go to the shop’s preferences and enter basic information. For that please

visit http://localhost:8000/manage
login with admin/admin
browse to Shop / Preferences
```

https://lightning-fast-shop.readthedocs.org/en/version-0.6/introduction/getting_started.html